# Current density $J$ when θ = 90°

Tags: electric-current, vectors

I've searched a lot on the internet, but so far, nothing has been able to resolve my doubt completely. So here it goes,

We know that,
$ I = \vec J • \vec A $ 
So, $ J = \frac {I}{Acosθ} $

Now, consider θ = 90° 
[image] 
I = 0 (since the area vector and current density are perpendicular, ZERO current flows *through* the area).

But what about J? I could think of these possibilities, please elaborate on these -

1. J = 0 
   Since I through the area is zero, $ J = \frac {0}{Acosθ} = 0 $
2. J = infinite 
   Since the component of the area vector along the flow of current is zero, $ J = \frac {I}{0} = ∞ $
3. J = undefined 
   Since, I through the area is zero, and the area perpendicular to I too is zero, so $ J = \frac {I}{Acosθ} = \frac {0}{0} = undefined $

Sidenote - This might seem very trivial, but this has been bugging me for a week now! Kindly help.

Edit - I've come to think that J is going to be infinite. Here's my logic - As J is inversely proportional to the area of cross section, it'll increase as we reduce the area...so here we can say that as the area approaches zero (becomes infinitesimally small), current density becomes bigger and bigger, say infinitely larger. Please clarify if I'm wrong.

I referred to this site for the readings - [https://unacademy.com/content/nda/study-material/physics/current-density/#:~:text=As%20a%20result%2C%20the%20larger,a%20smaller%20cross%2Dsectional%20area](https://unacademy.com/content/nda/study-material/physics/current-density/#:%7E:text=As%20a%20result%2C%20the%20larger,a%20smaller%20cross%2Dsectional%20area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the scalar product
$$ I = \vec{J} \cdot \vec{A} = J \cdot A \cdot \cos(\theta) $$

In this case $I=0$ since $\cos(90°)=0$

But this mean that you can consider any value $J \in \mathbb{R}$ or $A \in \mathbb{R}$.

Obviously we know that a current density vector or an area vector cannot have infinite value. At the same time, one (or both of them) can be equal to zero but this is more of a trivial case since you would considering the flux of nothing trough a surface that does not exists.

From a physical perspective, in a situation like this, with an angle of $90°$, you cannot infer much more on the values of $\vec{J}$ or $\vec{A}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, I understood the point of J and A taking any real values. However, can we visualise this issue like this - As J is inversely proportional to the area of cross section, it'll increase as we reduce the area...so here we can say that as the area approaches zero (becomes infinitesimally small), current density becomes bigger and bigger, say infinitely larger?

I referred to this site -  https://unacademy.com/content/nda/study-material/physics/current-density/#:~:text=As%20a%20result%2C%20the%20larger,a%20smaller%20cross%2Dsectional%20area.

Comment: @ApogeePoint here you are talking about "cross-section area" which is the case of $\theta = 0° \implies \cos(\theta)=1$. In this case, the equation effectively becomes $J = \frac{I}{A}$ and, if $I = const.$ we have $\lim_{A \to 0}J = \infty$. But again, this is a trivial example since it is not very useful to consider a surface that does not exists.

Comment: Okay, things have become a bit clearer, but please answer this one last question - Why is it *not* very useful to consider a surface that does not exists, by applying limits? What problems arise and what other possibilities/solutions are there?

Comment: @ApogeePoint sorry if I answer several days later, hope the answer will still be useful.
A current refers to the movement of some charges (usually electrons). Anyway, those charges physically exists somewhere and have a more or less defined size. For that reason, the concept of current density is useful if these particle have a surface to "pass trough".

Answer (score 0):

Current, $I$, is not a vector but current density, $\vec J$, is a vector and its direction is the same as that of the velocity of positive charges, $\vec v$,  with $\vec J = \rho \vec v$ where $\rho$ is the charge density.

For some angle $\theta$ you can think of the current density as having two components, one perpendicular to the area, $J\cos \theta$, and the other tangential to the area, $J\sin \theta$.

[image]

Thus the current passing through area $d\vec A$ is $I = \vec J\cdot d\vec A = \vec J\cdot \hat n \,dA = J\,dA\,\cos \theta$.

If $\theta =90^\circ$ there is no current passing through the area.

For this example with $\theta = 90^\circ$ your inversion of the equation $I = \vec J \cdot d\vec A $ to $ J = \frac {I}{dA\,\cos\theta} $ is not valid because you are attempting to divide by $\cos 90^\circ \Rightarrow \underbrace {0}_{I} = J\,dA\,\underbrace{0}_{\cos 90^\circ} $.